# Very different results of NIntegrate using different methods: which one to believe

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

Consider the following function:

```
SpectrumEHth[th_, Eh_] = Exp[-(Eh/300)]*Cos[th]^20
DiracDeltaArgument[mS_, mh_, ES_, Eh_, ph_, cosa_] = 
  mh^2 - 2*ES*Eh + 2*Sqrt[ES^2 - mS^2]*ph*cosa;
Cosa[th_, tS_, cosfh_] = cosfh*Sin[th]*Sin[tS] + Cos[th]*Cos[tS];
Print["Solutions of the DiracDeltaArgument = 0 in terms of     \
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(E\), \(h\)]\):"]
DiracDeltaEhSolution[ES_, cosa_, mS_, mh_] = 
 Eh /. Solve[
   DiracDeltaArgument[mS, mh, ES, Eh, Sqrt[Eh^2 - mh^2], cosa] == 0, 
   Eh]
Print["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(E\), \(h\)]\) must be real - restriction  \
   on \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(E\), \(S\)]\):"]
DiracDeltaESSolution[cosa_, mS_, mh_] = 
 ES /. Solve[
    Simplify[
      DiracDeltaEhSolution[ES, cosa, mS, mh][[1]] - 
       DiracDeltaEhSolution[ES, cosa, mS, mh][[2]]] == 0, ES][[4]]
DiracDeltaDerivative1[ES_, cosa_, mS_, mh_] = 
  Abs[D[DiracDeltaArgument[mS, mh, ES, Eh, Sqrt[Eh^2 - mh^2], cosa], 
     Eh] /. {Eh -> DiracDeltaEhSolution[ES, cosa, mS, mh][[1]]}];
DiracDeltaDerivative2[ES_, cosa_, mS_, mh_] = 
  Abs[D[DiracDeltaArgument[mS, mh, ES, Eh, Sqrt[Eh^2 - mh^2], cosa], 
     Eh] /. {Eh -> DiracDeltaEhSolution[ES, cosa, mS, mh][[2]]}];
D4PDtSDESdthdfh1[mS_, tS_, th_, fh_, ES_] = 
  1/(2*Pi) Sin[tS]*
   Sqrt[ES^2 - 
     mS^2]*(SpectrumEHth[th, 
       DiracDeltaEhSolution[ES, Cosa[th, tS, Cos[fh]], mS, 125][[1]]/
        125]/DiracDeltaDerivative1[ES, Cosa[th, tS, Cos[fh]], mS, 
       125] + SpectrumEHth[th, 
       DiracDeltaEhSolution[ES, Cosa[th, tS, Cos[fh]], mS, 125][[2]]/
        125]/DiracDeltaDerivative2[ES, Cosa[th, tS, Cos[fh]], mS, 
       125]);
```

I am interested in the integral

```
dPdtS1[mS_, tS_, method_] := 
 NIntegrate[
  D4PDtSDESdthdfh1[mS, tS, th, fh, ES], {th, 0, Pi}, {fh, 0, 
   2*Pi}, {ES, mS, 
   DiracDeltaESSolution[Cosa[th, tS, Cos[fh]], mS, 125]}, 
  Method -> method]
```

The integral is defined for 0< mS < 62.5, 0 < ts < Pi. The problem is that using different methods of integration I get completely different results. For example, evaluating dPdtS1[61, Pi/7, method] once, I got

"MonteCarlo", 187 and 146 for the integral and error estimates;

"GlobalAdaptive", 15356 and 2780 for the integral and error estimates;

"QuasiMonteCarlo", 52.21 and 27.89 for the integral and error estimates;

"AdaptiveMonteCarlo", 4559 and 397 for the integral and error estimates.

Moreover, by relaunching the integral I get completely different results. What is a possible reason for such discrepancy, which method to believe and how to get correct result?

Comment: Most likely the integral diverges. Could that be the reason?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform : it seems that the integrand is singular at $\cos(a) = \pm 1$. This is strange, as I expected it to be perfectly finite.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform : after isolating these points from the integral by adding UnitStep[cosa+0.99]*UnitStep[0.99-cosa] to the integrand I obtain similar answers with "GlobalAdaptive" and "MonteCarlo" methods. However, I am wondering whether this procedure is correct.

Answer (score -1):

Somewhat changing your `dPdtS1[mS_, tS_, method_]`:

```
dPdtS1[mS_, tS_, method_] := NIntegrate[ D4PDtSDESdthdfh1[mS, tS, th, fh, ES], 
{th, 0, Pi}, {fh, 0, 2*Pi}, {ES, mS, DiracDeltaESSolution[Cosa[th, tS, Cos[fh]], mS, 125]}, 
  Method -> method, AccuracyGoal -> 3, AccuracyGoal -> 3, WorkingPrecision -> 12]
```

, I obtain results which are in accordance:

```
dPdtS1[61, Pi/7, "MonteCarlo"]
```

> NIntegrate::maxp: The integral failed to converge after 50100 integrand evaluations. NIntegrate obtained 52.5526999394`12. and 22.9452125755`12. for the integral and error estimates. 
>   52.5526999394

```
dPdtS1[61, Pi/7, "QuasiMonteCarlo"]
```

> NIntegrate::maxp: The integral failed to converge after 50000 integrand evaluations. NIntegrate obtained 52.210452015`12. and 27.8916947548`12. for the integral and error estimates.52.2104520150

```
dPdtS1[61, Pi/7, "AdaptiveMonteCarlo"]
```

> 33.9967243466

```
dPdtS1[61, Pi/7, "GlobalAdaptive"]
```

> NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 27 recursive bisections in th near {th,fh,ES} = {0.14285714808198512200893945143233513185940146362578446566502126,8.9357332852024803908579020738908780656678045758304735988042582*10^-9,0.85551545010073033110760179589159365998596592914990664529781283}. NIntegrate obtained 7.0614090929455441703246801141021013462800610267368803292524564`62.*^6 and 149106.51130461280006735594201383218480741243488771852350942262`62. for the integral and error estimates.7.06140909295*10^6

It seems `"GlobalAdaptive"` is not an appropriate method to this end. You may play with options.

Comment: By relaunching the integral that uses "MonteCarlo" method with your set ups I get completely different results each time.

Comment: @John Taylor: Yes, but each time the result is in accordance with other results, e.g. NIntegrate::maxp: The integral failed to converge after 50100 integrand evaluations. NIntegrate obtained 28.393921726`12. and 7.83918101685`12. for the integral and error estimates. for my second execution.

Comment: Since "MonteCarlo" samples the function randomly, you'll generally get different results from different runs.